# Can't sign blackberry android app: Server response did not contain version

Tags: android, code-signing, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I'm trying to sign my Blackberry Android (ported) app for release to App World, but I can't get the tool to work. I've tried the eclipse plugin, the command line tools, and the online tool, but none will work. The eclipse plugin and command line tool just say:

```
Error: Server response did not contain version.
```

The online tool says that:

```
This APK was already packaged and signed, please update the APK’s version number to package again
```

Even though I've never successfully packaged it before. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Try incrementing the version number and sign it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved! It turns out that I did need to increase the version number, even though it had never successfully signed. The Blackberry signing server decided that versions 1 and 2 had already been signed (though they hadn't), so I just had to keep going until it worked.

```
Error: Server response did not contain version.
```

This error made me think that that wasn't the problem, but apparently *both* errors mean that the version is already in use. Just keep incrementing the version number until it works.

Comment: my problem also solved with it...but i think its worst problem..blackberry and RIM should work on this problem..otherwise it make people mad

Comment: I've faced the same error while requesting debug token on terminal. I noticed that there was a debug token already locating in the specified path. Just delete and request it again.

Answer (score 1):

Need to increase the version code, until it works. This [link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Code-signing-request-failed-because-this-file-has-been/ta-p/798291) might be helpful